# Cordova run android

Tags: android, cordova

I was working with my app, and I was doing `cordova run android` and it was all working fine, until i started getting this error.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':debugCompileClasspath'.
```

> Could not find play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/15.0.1/play-services-basement-15.0.1.aar
>   Could not find support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/27.1.1/support-v4-27.1.1.aar

i checked those links and they are not working, but I dont know how to fix my error to keep building my app. My android target is 27

Edit:
I also tried adding `google()` to my `build.gradle` but didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into the same problem this morning, play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1) is not currently available on jcenter().

Fixed issue by adding: maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } above: jcenter() in project and app level build.gradle scripts.

E.g.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    jcenter()

}
```

From:

[Could not find play-services-basement.aar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563407/could-not-find-play-services-basement-aar)