# android studio how to solve Failed to resolve: play-services-basement?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i dont know why this error come Failed to resolve: play-services-basement when i add volley library how to solve?

this is build gradle (level project )  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ6Eg.png)

and this is build gradle (level app)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p24Ej.png)

i have tried to invalidate cache and restart but not effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this issue before when I put `jcenter()` before `google()` in project level `build.gradle`.

When I changed the order and put `google()` before `jcenter()` in `build.gradle` the problem no longer exists.

A good explanation is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51213879/5575410)

Your final project level `build.gradle` should look like this

```
sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      ...
      ...
  }

  dependencies {
      ...
      ...
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      ...
  }
}
```