# play-services dependencies error, gradle build failed

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 11.4.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app: dependencies.

What is this error, spend 2 hours but not getting the root cause.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Such kind of error:**

Gradle sync failed: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Gradle sync failed: Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.

The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.0,15.0.0], [15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 15.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Gradle sync failed: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

**Using below version:**
class path gradleBuildVersion = "3.1.4", class path playServicesVersion ="4.1.0" googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1" fireBasePlayServicesVersion ="16.0.1"

Comment: what does your root and project build.gradle file look like?

Comment: Have you recently changes/add any new dependency or version ? Please share your gradle code

Comment: maybe , somehow , related to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563407/could-not-find-play-services-basement-aar/51213879#51213879

Comment: Question edited