# How to resolve these errors in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, maven-2, jcenter

I'm trying to connect  Firebase to my project. but when the project is synced I'm getting these errors repeatedly. please help me resolve this issue.

```
Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.1/google-services-4.0.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.1/google-services-4.0.1.pom 
sync failed 47s 272ms Run build 45s 783ms Load build 1s 336ms Configure build 44s 341ms Load projects 83ms rootProject 127ms Configure project : 44s 90ms Apply plugin org.gradle.help-tasks Apply script build.gradle 44s 83ms Resolve dependencies of :classpath 43s 860ms Download dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/…  21s 18ms Download jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.1/…    21s 2ms
```

Comment: disable offline work with gradle if enabled

Comment: it's not helping

Comment: it says resolve dependency of the class path

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51213879/7949696

Answer (score 0):

In your grade file, you need to add google() for repositories like below. If it is already there, you need to move it to up inside repositories.(google() should be there before jcenter()). I also faced the same issue and this is the way that I solved. 
[Could not find play-services-basement.aar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563407/could-not-find-play-services-basement-aar/51213879#51213879)

```
allprojects {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
  }
```