# How to resolve Firebase could not find firebase-auth-icense.aar issue?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have been developing apps using firebase for over an year now. Today when I open Android Studio suddenly all my projects built on Firebase are throwing the following error:

```
Error:Could not find firebase-auth-license.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-license:12.0.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth-license/12.0.1/firebase-auth-license-12.0.1.aar
```

Tried fixing it with many things like updating sdk build tools, google play services etc but still getting same error.

Following is my gradle file:

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "**********",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

        applicationId "*****"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        resConfig("en")
        versionCode 11
        versionName "2.21"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    //    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
    // Single target that includes all FirebaseUI libraries
    //    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    compile project(':checkbox')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.+'

    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.master.android:permissionhelper:1.3'
    compile 'com.stone.vega.library:VegaLayoutManager:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.7.1, 3.99.99]'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I had a similar issue two days ago.  This question helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563407/could-not-find-play-services-basement-aar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was `compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.7.1, 3.99.99]'`.
I just replaced it with `compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'` and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.2.1'
```

In your top level `build.gradle` file please be sure to have the latest version of Google Service plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Comment: Hi Darshan! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hey Alex, the problem was with onesignal version. Thanks for your help.